# Where did the sonic device originate?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, arrow

In the second season of *Arrow*, we're introduced to Canary, who wields a technological version of the comic's Black Canary's metahuman ability - the sonic device.  But I don't recall hearing where this device came from.  Did Canary make it herself?  Did it come from the League of Assassins?

What's the origin of Canary's sonic device?

Comment: Do you mean Sara or Laurel?

Comment: Sara. Laurel is Black Canary, Sara was just plain Canary.

Answer (score 4):

Sara Lance (Canary) never used the Canary Cry. She just used [Sonic device](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_device).

[image]

[Canary Cry](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Canary_Cry) was later modified from said sonic device by Cisco Ramon for Laurel Lance (Black Canary).

[image]

[image]

Now if you meant who made sonic devic? It is not to big of a deal for technology. World already made [Sonic and ultrasonic weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_weapon) (USW) even if they are bit larger than hand held sonic device. So with League of Assassins resources they probably just made it smaller and they are origin of Sonic Device seeing that Sara was part of their organisation.

Comment: If it came from the League, then why do no other League members have their own technological weapons?  Why is it unique amongst their members?

Comment: Well I presume that every assassin has different weapons on what skill best suits him. When Oliver was in League he still used bow ans arrow and not sword like Ra's al Ghul. So it is possible that Sara was not only one who used sonic device.  Now we are not shown all League members but I know that in comics there are many technology using members of League like Expediter(computer expert) or Owens(uses sniper). To bad we are mostly shown expendable minions and not big members

Answer (score 2):

In the TV *Arrow*verse, it's actually Cisco Ramon (from the *Flash*) who creates the Canary Cry device. **Laurel** asks him to create something special for her at the beginning of one of the crossover episodes, giving him one of Sara's sonic weapons from the League of Assassins. Cisco delivers it, in person, at the very end of the episode (I'm pretty sure it was "All Star Team Up", but I'm not positive... they do a LOT of Flash/Arrow crossover episodes). In typical Cisco fashion, he also gives it a neat name.

Edit: updated names so you don't have to play the pronoun game

Comment: If memory serves that was in the first crossover between Flash and Arrow if that helps.

Comment: Keen clarified in a comment (on a now deleted answer) that he meant Sara, rather than her sister Laurel (who was the one Cisco built the device for).

Comment: Sara never had Canary Cry, she used sonic device and I believe that it was made by League of Assassins since she was part of that organisation